# Modelling if-then-else-logic in MILP/MIP

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I would like to model the following for a [mixed-integer linear programming problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming):
Let y be a binary and x1 and x2 be continuous variables, whereas k1 is an invariant parameter.

```
if y == 1 then:  
    x2 = k1*x1   
else (y == 0):  
    x2 = 0
```

First idea that comes to mind is to do something like:

```
x2 >= k1*x1 - M*(1-y)  
x2 <= k1*x1 - M*(1-y)
```

But here M would have to be k1*x1 and  is therefore not an invariant parameter anymore. Does anyone have a better idea. Thank you!

Comment: I would just create a function and then pass on the value as needed. And maybe store it in a Matrix for fast computation.

Answer (score 0):

Per your problem :
y  : binary_variable
x1 : continous_variable
x2 : continous_variable

Please see equations below:

```
x2 <= u*y
x2 <= k1*x1
x2 >= k1*x1 − u*(1 − y)
x2 >= 0

u is the upper bound on k1*x1
0 <= k1*x1 <= u
```

you don't require a big M over here.

when y == 1 => x2 == k1*x1 
when y == 0 => x2 == 0